# Does equality of polynomials imply equality of matrix polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Say,$~~f(x) = h(x)g(x)~~$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ are polynomials with real coefficients.

Let $B$ be any non-negative square matrix. Can we always say $f(B) = h(B)g(B)?~$ Does it hold for any square matrix $B$? Can we formally prove this, if true?

Here $~f(B), g(B), h(B)$ are the matrix polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_polynomial).

Any hints or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $h(B)g(B)$ in the case that $B$ is not a square matrix?

Comment: @JMoravtiz  Oh my bad, $B$ is a square matrix.

Comment: If when you consider a polynomial as a matrix polynomial, you replace constants with corresponding multiples of identity matrices, you should find that $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ for all $x$ implies that $f(B)=h(B)g(B)$ for all square $B$.  The reverse implication is also true, remembering that $1\times 1$ matrices act just like real numbers.  Remember how polynomial equality acts: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^k\alpha_n x^n = \sum\limits_{n=0}^k\beta_n x^n$ for all $x$ if and only if $\alpha_i=\beta_i$ for all $i\in\{0,1,\dots,k\}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the reply. If you replace constants with multiples of identity matrices, wouldn't we have polynomial matrices(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_matrix) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to see where the different formulas live. If you write $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ the two members live in **formal expressions** but they are equal when they are evaluated as polynomials. Now, given a matrix $B$ there is a map (call it $\phi_B$) from the polynomials to the matrices such that 
$$
\phi_B(P+Q)=\phi_B(P)+\phi_B(Q)\ ;\ \phi_B(\alpha P)=\alpha\phi_B(P)\ ;\ 
\phi_B(PQ)=\phi_B(P)\phi_B(Q)\qquad (*)
$$ 
and one sees that $\phi_B(P)=P(B)$. If fact, this map $\phi_B$ is the unique map $\phi : k[X]\to M(n,k)$ which satisfies $(*)$, $\phi(1)=I$ and $\phi(X)=B$. So, if two expressions (however different as expressions) evaluate as the same polynomial (as $X^2-1$ and $(X-1)(X+1)$) their value at $B$ are the same. Expressions are better understood when written with *tree-like structures.* For instance $X^2-1$ reads (sorry but I am a bit clumsy in Mathjax drawings)
\begin{array}{cccccc}
  &  & - &  \\
  &╱&   &╲  \\
 & * &   & 1 & \\
╱ & &╲ &   & &  \\
X &  & X & &  
\end{array}
whereas $(X-1)(X+1)$ reads
\begin{array}{cccccc}
  &  & * &  \\
  &╱&   &╲  \\
 & - &   &  & +\\
╱ & &╲ &   ╱ & &╲  \\
X &  & 1 & X &  & 1
\end{array}
You can represent any polynomial expression like this. Identities are statements like $T_1=T_2$ where $T_i$ are formal expressions but are equal when evaluated within the realm of polynomials.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't quite understand your argument as I am not able to relate it to something I know. Can you explain more about the map? Where does it arise? Are you just saying that the product polynomials and the left hand side polynomial have the same co-effecients, so the matrix polynomials evaluate the same?

Comment: Yes, I put details

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is .

$f(x)$,$h(x)$, and $g(x)$ are polynomials in $x$, therefore, $f(B)$,$h(B)$, and $g(B)$ are polynomials in $B$.

The addition and multiplication of matrices enjoy the same properties as addition and multiplication of real numbers except the commutative property of multiplication.

Since we are dealing with only one matrix $B$ in this question, the commutative property is also valid for polynomials in $B$.

Comment: So this holds for any square matrix then.

Comment: Yes, it does as long as the matrix operations are possible.